# Customizing date form in symfony 2

Tags: forms, date, symfony, twig

I am trying to alter the date_widget using symfony2 and twig. By default a field of years has 10 year options, e.g. 5 years before and 5 years after the today date. I would like just the years until now. How can I change it? I have already looked at 'form_div_layout.html.twig' but I see that it's not the place of this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the 'years' option when building your date widget. For example:

```
$builder->add('foobar_date','date', array(
    'years' => range(date('Y') -5, date('Y')),
));
```

More info on how to configure the date widget: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html

**(edited)**

Comment: By this way I am getting PHP error. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR
This is my code: [code]
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
             ->add('region')
            ->add('category')
            ->add('subject')
            ->add('start_date','date', array('years' => range(date('Y')-50, date('Y')))
            ->add('finish_date')
            ->add('content', 'textarea')
            ->add('image', 'file')
            ->add('email', 'email')
        ;
    }

Comment: You probably need one more ) after your date options array, like this: array('years' => range(date('Y')-50, date('Y'))))

Comment: Awesome sir. helped me