# How to customize the Date type in Symfony form?

Tags: forms, date, symfony

By default in Date type with 'widget' => 'choice', we see that the start year in the box is 2007. I want to change it so that the start year will be 2012 (and the choices will be from 2007  to 2017 as it is now).
 How can I do that?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9968207/1218997) answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [`years` option](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#years) of the Date type.

Comment: Of course I've seen it. But for now I did not understand how it solves my problem. But now I tried to do something like this -> add ('finish_date', 'date', array (
'years' => range (date ('Y'), date ('Y') -10),
And this really helped. It's probably what you meant.